# Was there something in Lord Palmerston's career that made him associated with temporary appointments becoming permanent?

Tags: 19th-century, british-empire, quotes

While [researching the quote](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/50691/did-milton-friedman-say-that-nothing-was-so-permanent-as-a-temporary-government) "nothing more permanent than something temporary", I stumbled upon this quote from the "[Royal United Service Institution Journal](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Royal_United_Service_Institution_Journal/aTgkLN297KUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22permanent%20as%20a%20temporary%22&pg=PA154&printsec=frontcover)" from 1888:

> I fear they will verify Lord Palmerston's saying, that nothing is so permanent as a temporary appointment, not improbably our grand-children, visiting the Cape on pleasure or on business, will see this astounding, this everlasting memento, of our foresight.

I presume that the attribution was apocryphal rather than a literal quote but why was [Lord Palmerston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_John_Temple,_3rd_Viscount_Palmerston) chosen for the attribution? Was there a famous episode in his career that resulted in him being associated with temporary appointments? Or perhaps he really did use this phrase and was directly famous for it?

I tried checking Lord Palmerston's biography but couldn't find any relevant episodes.

Comment: It seems quite possible that someone actually heard him say that. Which of course would not mean that he hadn't in turn heard it from someone else.

Comment: It might be based on a misremembered bit of debate in 10 Dec 1813; see https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Parliamentary_Register/J2QxAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22nothing+more+permanent%22+%22temporary%22&pg=PA158&printsec=frontcover  at about p.158.